# How to read coordinates data from a BLOB?

Tags: oracle, arcgis, raw-data

There is coordinate data  which is stored in a BLOB, similar to the arcgis ST_GEOMETRY type of points. The storage contains the byte stream of the point coordinates that define the geometry like this:

[image: Hex dump of a blob]

How can I get the data from the BLOB in Oracle?

Comment: "similar to the arcgis ST_GEOMETRY type of points" Well, is it ArcGIS ST_GEOMETRY? If so, you probably need to use an ArcGIS client to read the data. If it's only "similar" to ST_GEOMETRY, then I'm not sure what you would do.

Answer (score 1):

BLOBs are binary data. They could contain literally anything. Oracle has no built-in mechanism for extracting data from a BLOB. Your options are:

1. Whatever part of your application wrote the binary data should be responsible for unpacking and displaying the data.
2. Write some PL/SQL to retrieve the data using UTL_RAW functions to work with binary data. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71353) Doing this requires you to understand how the program which wrote the binary structured it.

This is why storing data in binary is usually a bad idea. Sure, you save space but essentially this obfuscates the data and imposes a toll on using it. If storage is that much of an issue consider compression instead.